# Convert jobjectarray into vector<uint8_t>

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, byte

I'm using JNI to pass a jobjectarray from java (which is in fact a byte[][]).

I'd to convert this into a usable "byte array" in the form of uint8_t* or vector (ideally the latter) so that it is compatible with all of my existing code which uses it in those forms.

Any advice on how I can best do this? Open to using jbytearray instead if that's cleaner...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if `vector<uint8_t*>` would be a good idea here. A `vector<vector<uint8_t>>` might be better.

```
jsize numRows = env->GetArrayLength(objArray);
vector<vector<uint8_t>> v(numRows);
```

Write a loop where you get the n:th row from the `jobjectArray`:

```
jbyteArray bytes = (jbyteArray) env->GetObjectArrayElement(objArray, n);
```

Then get a pointer to the actual bytes in that row, and insert those bytes into your vector:

```
jsize numBytes = env->GetArrayLength(bytes);
uint8_t *data = (uint8_t*) env->GetByteArrayElements(bytes, NULL);
std::copy(data, data + numBytes, std::back_inserter(v[n]));
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(bytes, JNI_ABORT);
```

Immediately deleting the local reference to `bytes` afterwards may be a good idea, to avoid overflowing the local reference table if you've got a large number of rows:

```
env->DeleteLocalRef(bytes);
```

---

Although a more efficient approach than a `byte[][]` might be to use a `java.nio.ByteBuffer` obtained with `allocateDirect`.

Comment: What is the `n` from std::copy(data, data + numBytes, std::back_inserter(v[n])); How can I insert all array's characters? Can I choose for loop?

Comment: `n` is the row number.